# Problem with creating breaks and setting colours for choropleth maps in RStudio

Tags: r, ggplot2, choropleth, rgdal

I am trying to plot a choropleth map of Ethiopia that shows the number of internally displaced persons (IDPs) as a percentage of the total population for each Zone (county). I have uploaded the Ethiopia Shapefile to R (Ethiopia_geoboundaries_ADM2), as well as the %IDP data for Ethiopia (Ethiopia_Rmap) and merged them. However, when I use spplot, the colour range only fits the current data range. I have other countries which I want to compare these results to, so would like a uniform set of colour breaks for each map.

The colour breaks I would like are: <5%, 5-10%, 10-25%, 25-50%, 50-75%, 75%+

Current code and output:

```
> setwd("~/Documents/Acumen_Data/IDMC_Map_Data/Ethiopia")
> library(spdep)
> library(rgdal)
> library(sf)
> library(terra)
> Ethiopia_Rmap <- read_excel("Ethiopia_Rmap.xlsx")
> Ethiopia_geoBoundaries_ADM2 <- readOGR(dsn = ".", layer = "eth_admbnda_adm2_csa_bofedb_2021")
> Ethiopia_Static_Map = merge(Ethiopia_geoBoundaries_ADM2,Ethiopia_Rmap,by.x="ADM2_EN",by.y="Zone")
> ColourPalette = brewer.pal(n=7, name="PuBu")
> spplot(Ethiopia_Static_Map,"IDP_Perc", col.regions=ColourPalette)
```

[This is the output map currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erZPp.png)

[This is the Ethiopia_Rmap population percentage data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUcPI.png)

[This is the Ethiopia shapefile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqtEi.png)

I want a map that has a legend somewhat like this, rather than from 0-50. I think this means somehow defining set breaks of class intervals? Please help! thank you!

[Sample legend - doesnt have to be these exact colours!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlMU3.png)

Ethiopia_geoboundaries_ADM2 data is from this link - https://data.humdata.org/dataset/cb58fa1f-687d-4cac-81a7-655ab1efb2d0/resource/63c4a9af-53a7-455b-a4d2-adcc22b48d28/download/eth_adm_csa_bofedb_2021_shp.zip

Ethiopia_Rmap data example using dput

> Ethiopia_Rmap_Structure = dput(Ethiopia_Rmap[1:30,])

> Ethiopia_Rmap = structure(
> list(
> Region = c(
> "Afar",
> "Afar",
> "Afar",
> "Afar",
> "Afar",
> "Amhara",
> "Amhara",
> "Amhara",
> "Amhara",
> "Amhara",
> "Amhara",
> "Amhara",
> "Amhara",
> "Amhara",
> "Amhara",
> "Amhara",
> "Benishangul-Gumuz Region",
> "Benishangul-Gumuz Region",
> "Gambela",
> "Gambela",
> "Harari",
> "Oromia",
> "Oromia",
> "Oromia",
> "Oromia",
> "Oromia",
> "Oromia",
> "Oromia",
> "Oromia",
> "Oromia"
> ),
> Zone = c(
> "Aswi /Zone 1",
> "Fanti /Zone 4",
> "Gabi /Zone 3",
> "Hari /Zone 5",
> "Kilbati /Zone 2",
> "Argoba (special Woreda)",
> "Awi",
> "East Gojam",
> "North Gondar",
> "North Shewa (AM)",
> "North Wello",
> "Oromia",
> "South Gondar",
> "South Wello",
> "Wag Hamra",
> "West Gojam",
> "Assosa",
> "Metekel",
> "Agnewak",
> "Nuwer",
> "Harari",
> "Arsi",
> "Bale",
> "Borena",
> "East Hararge",
> "East Wellega",
> "Guji",
> "Horo Gudru Wallega",
> "Jimma",
> "Kelem Wallega"
> ),
> IDP_Population = c(
> 22668,
> 1531,
> 28011,
> 2580,
> 41786,
> 4498,
> 28622,
> 20633,
> 25407,
> 66296,
> 30243,
> 7370,
> 28704,
> 24292,
> 38934,
> 143028,
> 28603,
> 94798,
> 5296,
> 39208,
> 3037,
> 4064,
> 10650,
> 220540,
> 143853,
> 140374,
> 100972,
> 42496,
> 14893,
> 26351
> ),
> Total_Population = c(
> 641584,
> 333296,
> 328636,
> 254909,
> 489698,
> 42250,
> 1328104,
> 2845753,
> 4066517,
> 2464232,
> 1989563,
> 611456,
> 2701503,
> 3387395,
> 548884,
> 2755600,
> 492344,
> 441297,
> 204358,
> 172105,
> 283000,
> 3980967,
> 2119829,
> 1431922,
> 4035797,
> 1847649,
> 2073775,
> 859339,
> 3638103,
> 1191582
> ),
> IDP_Perc = c(
> 3.53,
> 0.46,
> 8.52,
> 1.01,
> 8.53,
> 10.65,
> 2.16,
> 0.73,
> 0.62,
> 2.69,
> 1.52,
> 1.21,
> 1.06,
> 0.72,
> 7.09,
> 5.19,
> 5.81,
> 21.48,
> 2.59,
> 22.78,
> 1.07,
> 0.1,
> 0.5,
> 15.4,
> 3.56,
> 7.6,
> 4.87,
> 4.95,
> 0.41,
> 2.21
> )
> ),
> row.names = c(NA,-30L),
> class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
> )

Comment: Apologies. Typo!

Comment: You are unlikely to receive a useful answer without making your code reproducible, so people can try out solutions. Instead of sharing pictures of data, which we can't use, share some example data using e.g. `dput` that illustrates your issue.

Comment: Thanks @Axeman, very new to all this!